# Read from GET endpoint and send to POST using Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have to implement a program where I have to read data from two different GET endpoints, do the data manipulation (business logic part) and send the data to a POST endpoint.
The idea seems to be like implementing apache kafka.

The catch- 
As soon as the both GET endpoints release the complete data (could be 10000 records or more), where the end of data is represented by special json message. 
The POST endpoint remains available only for 10 seconds.

My question-

1. How can I make GET request until the end of message is received (some sample program would be appreciated)
2. Can i achieve the goal without implementing apache kafka or can be done only through apache kafka (again some sample program would be appreciated)

Comment: I think SO is not the place for these kind of open questions.

Answer (score 1):

> can I make GET request until the end of message is received

A GET request is inherently blocking. You should get the full response already.

> Can i achieve the goal without implementing apache kafka or can be done only through apache kafka

It's not really clear what the goal is. Sounds like you have a typical ETL problem. Kafka doesn't do GET/POST

> The idea seems to be like implementing apache kafka.

Not really. The web server would emit its own events, the downstream server would pull those events, and/or others on its own. You wouldn't "push" anything into the "POST server" here.